# The use of the present perfect followed by the past simple

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Is the use of the past simple correct in the following context?

> Person A: Have you ever argued with your girlfriend?
>
> Person B: Yes, I have.
>
> Person A: what did you argue about?

Should have I used the present perfect as well in the second question.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the past simple: "what did you argue about", you are thinking of that specific occasion in the past when the argument took place and what you argued about.

If you use present perfect: "what have you argued about?", I would expect a number of different arguments, happening at different occasions over a period of time until now. "we have argued about lots of things".

Answer (score 1):

That example is precisely right.

Here's another:

Q: Have **you ever ridden** a bike?
A: Yes, I **have**.
Q: When **did you last ride** a bike?
A: I last **rode** a bike **yesterday.**

It is very common to move from a present perfect that signals the past without being specific to a past event that is specific. **This happens all the time in English.** *In fact, this is one way the past perfect versus the simple past is taught to ELLers.*

Q: **Have you understood** what I am saying?
A: Yes, I **have.**
Q: **How did you understand** it?
A: **I understood it** because your explanation is [or was] pretty clear.